# Advanced Calculus Question. Prove (sn + tn) is a Cauchy sequence

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Based on the definition of a Cauchy sequence, that if (sn) is a Cauchy sequence and (tn) is a Cauchy sequence, then (sn + tn) is a Cauchy sequence

I try to work from the definition that

|(Sn + tn) -(Sm + tm)| = |(sn-sm) +(tn - tm)| <= |sn - sm| + |tn = tm| <= 2Δ

How can can I get the thing like  |sn - sm| + |tn = tm| <= Δ? to prove by the definition of Cauchy sequence directly?

Comment: Both $(s_n)$ and $(t_n)$ are Cauchy, so their difference is less than $\epsilon/2.$

Comment: Can you explain a little bit. I think I got confused for this problem.

Comment: I meant you can bound $|s_n - s_m| < \epsilon/2$ because $(s_n)$ is Cauchy.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  To prove $s_n+t_n$is Cauchy, if I give you an $\epsilon$ you have to be able to find $N$ such that if $m,n \gt N, |(s_n+t_n)_(s_m+t_m)| \lt \epsilon$  But you have been told that each sequence is Cauchy.  So if you demand an $N$ such that if $n,m\gt N$ you have $|s_n-s_m| \lt \epsilon_s = \epsilon /2$ and similarly for $\epsilon _t=\epsilon /2$.....